Creating directories with wget
I need to download files from several pages, using wget -r -l 1 -nd -H --accept-regex 'https://blogspot.com/s[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{3}.pdf' -i list.txt; in the TXT file I have a list of all the pages from which I need to download, one per line, like
https://blogspot.com/test/001
https://blogspot.com/test/002
and so on.
I'm trying to create different folders for each source, so that all the files downloaded from https://blogspot.com/test/001 are in a folder named 001, all those from https://blogspot.com/test/002 are in a folder 002, and so on.
How could I do that?

see/use: How to parse each line of a text file as an argument to a command?

have you tried the -x switch to wget?

My problem isn't with parsing the text file, but creating the folders; the file is parsed and file are downloaded from each site in the TXT file. @StefanHegny I tried and I get folders, but from the address after --accept-regex, not from those in the TXT file.

You might use -P to instruct GNU wget to store download e.g.
wget -P examplepage -np -r -l 1 http://www.example.com

will store what it download inside examplepage directory. Said directory will be created if it does not exists yet.

I'm trying to create different folders for each source, so that all
the files downloaded from https://blogspot.com/test/001 are in a
folder named 001, all those from https://blogspot.com/test/002 are
in a folder 002, and so on.

I do not know if it possible with single wget call. You might use loop to process file line by line, for example let say urls.txt content is
http://www.example.com?page=001
http://www.example.com?page=002
http://www.example.com?page=003

and I wish 1st to into directory named 001, 2nd into directory named 002, 3rd into directory named 003 I could do that by
while read line; do
    dirname=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*page=//')
    wget -P "$dirname" "$line"
done < urls.txt

Explanation: I use while loop to process file named urls.txt line by line, I use GNU sed to prepare directory name by removing everything up to page= from url.

Thanks! I also tried with a for loop and it worked too.
